# Laravel: Query builder builder returning different result than actual mysql query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

i have table with a column name firmware_flash_result which is either fail or pass.
the Query builder is returning correct result for Pass but for failure it is returning wrong result.

Actual Query and result:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `payment_module_id`) 
 FROM `payment_prod_pograms` 
 WHERE `created_at` >= "2018-09-17 00:00:00" AND 
       (
        `payment_module_id` LIKE "PB10____18____" OR 
        `payment_module_id` LIKE "PM10____18____" 
       ) AND 
       CHAR_LENGTH(`payment_module_id`) = 14 AND 
       `firmware_flash_result` = "FAIL";

+-------------------------------------+
| COUNT(DISTINCT `payment_module_id`) |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   0 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Laravel Query Builder:

```
$payment_prod_failed_test = DB::table('payment_prod_pograms')
        ->where('created_at','>=','2018-09-17 00:00:00')
        ->whereRaw('char_length(payment_module_id) = 14')
        ->where('payment_module_id','like','%PB10____18____%')
        ->orWhere('payment_module_id','like','%PM10____18____%')
        ->where('firmware_flash_result','=','FAIL')
        ->distinct()
        ->count('payment_module_id');
```

the above query is returning result 453 which is not possible.

After some debugging i found that:

```
->orWhere('payment_module_id','like','%PM10____18____%')
```

is causing this error why is it?

there are 1515 entries in database and all of them are pass but this query is returning different result..
What i am doing wrong here ?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You have multiple condition and one of them is `orWhere('payment_module_id','like','%PM10____18____%')` and I guess it is not wrapped with `()` as in your SQL example but you get query:

Comment: but the same query is working fine in mysql ...

Comment: They are not the same:  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT payment_module_id) FROM payment_prod_pograms where created_at > '2018-09-17 00:00:00' AND payment_module_id LIKE '%PB10____18____%' OR payment_module_id LIKE '%PM10____18____%' AND CHAR_LENGTH(payment_module_id) = 14 AND firmware_flash_result = 'FAIL';` Your ORM version is lacking `()` around OR condition plus missing `%`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda i changed it but still same result.i guess order does'nt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping your where payment_module_id to be like %PB10____18____% or %PM10____18____% so you need to do the same in your eloquent query. This is done by using a closure.

```
$payment_prod_failed_test = DB::table('payment_prod_pograms')
        ->where('created_at','>=','2018-09-17 00:00:00')
        ->whereRaw('char_length(payment_module_id) = 14')
        ->where(function($query) { 
            $query->where('payment_module_id','like','%PB10____18____%')
                  ->orWhere('payment_module_id','like','%PM10____18____%');
        })
        ->where('firmware_flash_result','=','FAIL')
        ->distinct()
        ->count('payment_module_id');
```